# Range of values of $\beta$ for which $(x_1)^2+(x_2)^2+(x_3)^2 - \beta (2x_1x_2+2x_1x_3+2x_2x_3) \geq 0$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality

Find the range of values of $\beta$ for which $(x_1)^2+(x_2)^2+(x_3)^2 - \beta (2x_1x_2+2x_1x_3+2x_2x_3) \geq 0$ for all values of $x_1,x_2,x_3 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\forall \boldsymbol{x}\in \mathbb{R}^{3}$,

$$\lambda_{min} \Vert \boldsymbol{x} \Vert^2 \le
\boldsymbol{x}^T
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & -\beta & -\beta \\
  -\beta & 1 & -\beta \\
  -\beta & -\beta & 1
\end{pmatrix} \boldsymbol{x}
\le \lambda_{max} \Vert \boldsymbol{x} \Vert^2$$

The eigenvalues $\lambda$: $1+\beta$, $1+\beta$, $1-2\beta$

**Case I:**

$$0 \le 1+\beta \le 1-2\beta \implies -1\le \beta \le 0$$

**Case II:**

$$0 \le 1-2\beta \le 1+\beta \implies 0\le \beta \le \dfrac{1}{2}$$

> Combining,
>
> $$-1\le \beta \le \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Taking $\left(x_1,x_2,x_3\right):=(1,1,-2)$, we have
$$6-(-6)\beta\geq 0\text{ or }\beta \geq -1\,.$$
With $\left(x_1,x_2,x_3\right):=(1,1,1)$, we obtain
$$3-6\beta \geq 0\text{ or }\beta \leq \frac{1}{2}\,.$$
We shall show that all $\beta \in \left[-1,\frac{1}{2}\right]$ works.  For such $\beta$, we see that the required expression
$$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2-\beta \left(2x_1x_2+2x_1x_3+2x_3x_1\right)$$ equals
$$\left(\frac{1-2\beta}{3}\right)\left(x_1+x_2+x_3\right)^2+\left(\frac{1+\beta}{3}\right)\left(\left(x_1-x_2\right)^2+\left(x_1-x_3\right)^2+\left(x_3-x_1\right)^2\right) \geq 0\,.$$
The equality case when $\beta=-1$ is when $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$.  The equality case for $\beta=\frac{1}{2}$ is that $x_1=x_2=x_3$.  If $-1<\beta <\frac12$, then the equality case is $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$.